# Calling a function on Christmas day

Tags: javascript

I'm having a little bit of trouble trying to make it 'snow' only on Christmas day. I figured out how to grab the day but I'm not sure how make it call SnowStorm() correctly.

```
var christmas = {
  month: 11,
  date: 25
}

function isItChristmas() {
  var now = new Date();
  var isChristmas = (now.getMonth() == christmas.month && now.getDate() == christmas.date);

if (isChristmas)
    return ;
  else
    return ;
}

var snowStorm = null;

function SnowStorm() {
    (snowstorm code)

}

snowStorm = new SnowStorm();
```

Comment: Which bit are you stuck on specifically? The `isItChristmas` part? How to put your `snowStorm()` function into the empty `if()` statement? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the version if you are planning to make a function (not a class):

```
var christmas = {
  month: 12,
  date: 25
}

function isItChristmas() {
  var now = new Date();
  return (now.getMonth() == christmas.month && now.getDate() == christmas.date);
}

if (isItChristmas()){
    SnowStorm();
  }else{
    //not a christmas
}
    
function SnowStorm() {
    (snowstorm code)
}
```

Here's the one if you are planning to make a class:

```
var christmas = {
  month: 12,
  date: 25
}

function isItChristmas() {
  var now = new Date();
  return (now.getMonth() == christmas.month && now.getDate() == christmas.date);
}

var storm = new SnowStorm();

if (isItChristmas()){
    storm.Snow();
  }else{
    //not a christmas
}
    
function SnowStorm() {
    this.Snow = function(){
        (snowstorm code)
    }
}
```

Comment: The month of Christmas should likely be set to 11 because `.getMonth()` starts at 0 for January. (Alternatively, you could just -1 in the `getMonth()` part of the `isItChristmas()` function.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a boolean value from the `isItChristmas` function:

```
function isItChristmas() {
   var now = new Date();
   return (now.getMonth() + 1 == christmas.month && 
           now.getDate() == christmas.date);
}
```

and then call it:

```
function SnowStorm() {
    if (isItChristmas()) {
        // your snowstorm code here
        // that will execute only on Christmas
    }
}
```

By the way you will notice that the [`.getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) method returns the month from 0 to 11, so you need to add 1 as shown in my example, otherwise your code will run on 25th of November.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are not returning anything on the isItChristmas function.
Second, in the SnowStorm function just add

```
if (isItChristmas) {
    (your code here)
}
```