# Show DIV only in a certain date range

Tags: javascript, date

**Hi SO-Community,**

i figure this may be an amateur type of question, but i just could not find a proper solution anywhere:

I am trying to show a specific DIV only in Christmas Time via JavaScript. Here goes my code so far:

```
function WinterTime() {
var WinterStart = new Date(2017, 12, 21);
var WinterEnd = new Date(2017, 12, 27);
if 
(WinterStart <= CurrentDate && CurrentDate <= WinterEnd) {
song2.style.display = "block";
}
else {
song2.style.display = "none";
}
}
```

I defined the variable "song2" earlier in case you're wondering.

I figure this may be complete rubbish code but please show mercy since I am a total noob and just tried to learn from various other threats. 
I am grateful for your Feedback. :)

Regards

Jonas

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a function on Christmas day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631915/calling-a-function-on-christmas-day)

Comment: What exactly is your question? What happens when you run this code? Does song2 always/never appear? Also, see: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_display

Comment: Should we also assume CurrentDate is defined?

Comment: Months are zero indexed, December is 11 so `new Date(2017, 12, 21)` creates a date for 21 Jan, 2018.

Comment: I am sorry @deckeresq , maybe i should have been more precise: My goal is to always play the christmas song during the christmas days. This song (song2) is defined earlier and by now, it always appears.

Also, CurrentDate is defined before the function like this: 

var CurrentDate = new Date();

I hope thats the right way to do it. 

Also, thank you for the month indices, i fixed that. 

Appreciate all your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is fine, the implementation is a little off though. ;-)

```js
// Function names starting with a capital letter are,
// by convention, reserved for constructors.
// The function should accept a date or default to the current date
function winterTime(currentDate) {
  currentDate = currentDate || new Date();
  // Months are zero indexed, so for 21 December:
  var winterStart = new Date(2017, 11, 21);
  var winterEnd = new Date(2017, 11, 27);
  
  // Get a reference to the element
  var song2 = document.getElementById('song2');
  
  if (winterStart <= currentDate && currentDate <= winterEnd) {
    // Set display to '' (empty string) so the element adopts its default or inherited value
    song2.style.display = "";
    console.log('Winter');
    
  } else {
    song2.style.display = "none";
    console.log('Not winter');
  }
}

// Call function when page loaded
window.onload = winterTime;
```

```html
<div id="song1">Song 1</div>
<div id="song2">Song 2</div>
```

If you use some recently added features, you can apply the style using CSS fairly simply:

```js
function winterTime(currentDate = new Date()) {
  var winterStart = new Date(2017, 11, 21);
  var winterEnd = new Date(2017, 11, 27);
  var isWinter = winterStart <= currentDate && currentDate <= winterEnd;
  var song2 = document.getElementById('song2');
  song2.classList[isWinter? 'remove' : 'add']('hidden');

  // Just for testing
  console.log(isWinter? 'Winter' : 'Not winter');
}

// Call function when page loaded
window.onload = function() {
  winterTime(new Date(2017, 11, 25)); // Christmas day
};
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="song1">Song 1</div>
<div id="song2">Song 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work, but I've cleaned it up a bit.  I used console logging to show how your evaluation is working, you can adjust to work with your HTML as needed.

```
function winterTime(currentDate) {
  var winterStart = new Date(2017, 12, 21);
  var winterEnd = new Date(2017, 12, 27);
  if(winterStart <= currentDate && currentDate <= winterEnd) {
    // current date is within range
    console.log('true')
  } else {
    // current date is out of range
    console.log('false')
  }
}

winterTime(new Date()); // now
winterTime(new Date(2017, 12, 25)); // within range
```

https://jsfiddle.net/34dv5y9a/

Comment: Why create code elsewhere when you can use your code here to create a runnable snippet an not rely on external resources?